# JavaScript dates: toGMTString, but also ISO 8601 format?

Tags: javascript, date, format

Is there an easy way to convert a date object to GMT time, but also display in ISO 8601 format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to convert a date object to GMT time

Yes:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toGMTString()
```

> but also display in ISO 8601 format?

Function taken [form here](http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/) (they also have an ISO 8601 parser there)

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) { return n<10 ? '0'+n : n }
    return      d.getUTCFullYear()
    + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)
    + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate())
    + 'T' + pad(d.getUTCHours())
    + ':' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())
    + ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
    + 'Z'
}
```

Comment: [Date.prototype.toGMTString() is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)!

Answer (score 2):

*The best solution I've come across is to use the **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** javascript library and use the following code:*

To get the current ISO time with timezone information and milliseconds

```
now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
// "2013-03-08T20:11:11.234+0100"

now = moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z"
// "2013-03-08T19:11:11Z" <- better use the native .toISOString()
```

To get the ISO time of a native JavaScript Date object with timezone information but without milliseconds

```
var current_time = Date.now();
moment(current_time).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MDN date.toISOString() page which also includes cross-browser compatibility code.  Both ways create an ISO 8601 string from a date instance:

[MDN Page on date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)